# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient' when attemping to activate controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph in one of my controllers, however I keep running into an error everywhere I call that controller:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient' while attempting to activate 'HomeController'.

I'm not sure why this happens, this is how I initialize the controller

```
private readonly Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient;
public HomeController(Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
{
   this.graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(graphServiceClient));
}
```

Comment: Have you added the service for the dependency injection on `Startup`?

Comment: That helped, you can put this as the answer, just needed to add the scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chance are depending on how the service was registered that `IGraphServiceClient` used.

I would suggest refactoring the controller to depend on the abstraction.

```
private readonly IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient;

public HomeController(IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient) {
    this.graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(graphServiceClient));
}
```

If the DI container is still unable to resolve the abstraction that I suggest reviewing how the service was registered with the DI container, making sure that all dependencies are known to the container.

```
//...

services.AddScoped<IGraphServiceClient, GraphServiceClient>();

//...
```

I would take it a step further and register the client using `AddHttpClient` so that the HttpClient used can be pre-configured in one step

```
//...

services.AddHttpClient<IGraphServiceClient, GraphServiceClient>(client => {
    //...configure client.
});

//...
```

Comment: Not working on Blazor it gives compile error CS0246.