# Blazor + SignalR Core + Microsoft Identity Platform does not appear to authenticate on Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, signalr, microsoft-identity-platform

**Major updates**
.NET 6, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client v7.04, Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph 2.12.4 Microsoft.Graph 5.16

First of all there is apparently a known issue with SignalR + Microsoft Identity Framework, applying the workaround quoted here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34419#issuecomment-893698707 I was able to get past the error mentioned in that thread.

The error I am receiving seems to indicate the app id/client id is not propagating correctly. Is there a step I'm missing possibly in and Azure AD Blade?

The Hub

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace Aces.Fit.Web.Hubs
{
    [Authorize]
    [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] { "user.read" })]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        protected GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; }
        public ChatHub(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            GraphClient = graphServiceClient;
        }

        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            var user = await GraphClient.Me.GetAsync();
            if(user != null)
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user.DisplayName, message);
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the error on await `await GraphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();`:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[8]
      Failed to invoke hub method 'SendMessage'.
      Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: OnBehalfOfCredential authentication failed: AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - Key was found, but use of the key to verify the signature failed., Thumbprint of key used by client: 'F8A23743D9CD47B6D1A1FC66799A17A9B1D919EC', Found key 'Start=10/02/2022 18:06:49, End=10/02/2027 18:06:49', Please visit the Azure Portal, Graph Explorer or directly use MS Graph to see configured keys for app Id '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'. Review the documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments to determine the corresponding service endpoint and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to build a query request URL, such as 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'].
```

The Blazor View can be found at:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject IHttpContextAccessor Context
@implements IAsyncDisposable


<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>


<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Message:
        <input @bind="messageInput" size="50" />
    </label>
</div>
<button @onclick="Send" disabled="@(!IsConnected)">Send</button>

<hr>

<ul id="messagesList">
    @foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        <li>@message</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    private HubConnection? hubConnection;
    private List<string> messages = new List<string>();
    private string? userInput;
    private string? messageInput;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"),options =>
            {
                var container = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
                foreach (var item in Context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
                {
                    container.Add(new System.Net.Cookie(item.Key, item.Value) { Domain = Context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host, HttpOnly = true });
                }
                options.Cookies = container;
            })
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            var encodedMsg = $"{user}: {message}";
            messages.Add(encodedMsg);
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    private async Task Send()
    {
        if (hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", messageInput);
        }
    }

    public bool IsConnected =>
        hubConnection?.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the Program.cs:

```
using Aces.Fit.Web.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Aces.Fit.Web.Hubs;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication;
using Azure.Identity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using IdentityModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Aces.Fit.Web;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
          new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ConfigurationManager>(p => builder.Configuration);
///builder.Services.AddScoped<GraphServiceClientFactory>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<GraphServiceClient>("graph", client =>
{
    // Configure the HttpClient options
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com");
    // Add any additional configuration to the HttpClient
    // such as default headers or authentication
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<GraphServiceClient>(provider =>
{

    // Retrieve the necessary configuration values
    var clientId = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"];
    var tenantId = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"];
    var clientSecret = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:ClientSecret"];

    // Create the ConfidentialClientApplication using the configuration values
    var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")
        .Build();

    // Acquire a token for the client
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var authenticationResult = confidentialClientApplication
        .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync()
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();

    // Create the OnBehalfOfCredential using the acquired token
    var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(
        tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, authenticationResult.AccessToken);

    // Create the GraphServiceClient using the OnBehalfOfCredential
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential);

    return graphClient;
});


builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
          new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
});
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseResponseCompression();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");

});
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Comment: After checking your source code, I think the issue related to not register the `GraphServiceClient` successfully, you coud [follow the steps in this thread first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66319087/7687666). Waiting for your update.

Comment: @JasonPan I do not see IGraphServiceClient in 5.16, I have major revisions to what I am doing and am now recieving an error that has something to do with the ClientId/AppId not being set.